# Perform the MD5 function in Smarty Template Engine

Tags: php, templates, hash, smarty, md5

In a Smarty templated theme I would like to implement **MD5** within the template to get a unique hash based on a string and a salt. (Do not have access to the PHP calling the template, or this would be trivial). Smarty does not seem to have an MD5 function built into it. I thought I might be able to create a hash based on the length of the string and some other unique account information and by using Smarty's **Math** function, but was hoping there might be a better way to do this that I'm overlooking. Anyone have any thoughts or ideas on this? Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Smarty are you using?

Comment: Do you have access to the Smarty library code? In that case you could add your own custom modifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're just using the stock md5 function, you can use it as a modifier.

```
{$string|md5}
```

From documentation:

> All php-functions can be used as modifiers implicitly, as demonstrated in the example above. However, using php-functions as modifiers has two little pitfalls:
>
> - First - sometimes the order of the function-parameters is not the desirable one. Formatting $foo with {"%2.f"|sprintf:$foo} actually works, but asks for the more intuitive, like {$foo|string_format:"%2.f"} that is provided by the Smarty distribution.
> - Secondly - if $security is enabled, all php-functions that are to be used as modifiers have to be declared trusted in the MODIFIER_FUNCS element of the $security_settings array.

[Source v2](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl)
[Source v3](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl)

Comment: Perfect, thank you sir. The Smarty manual entry is called [language modifiers](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers), and the reason my searches couldn't find it was because if you read it also says "All php-functions can be used as modifiers implicitly".

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Haven't tested:

```
{assign var="string_to_hash" value="$string:$salt"}
{$string_to_hash|md5}
```